# Problemas con dropdown angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Estoy tratando de seleccionar una ciudad dependiendo de un determinado país con AngularJS.

**PROBLEMA:**
el problema radica en que cuando selecciono el pais y después la ciudad, se me borra del input el valor de país.
Nota: No borra el objecto completo solo hasta después de seleccionar una ciudad y volver a seleccionar el país, ahí si borra todo el objecto completo.

Sería de mucha ayuda cualquier solución. Muchas gracias

**Así tengo el código de pais**

```
function CargarListaRMOPaises() {
  if ($route.current.loadedTemplateUrl.indexOf("Crear.html") > 0 ||
    $route.current.loadedTemplateUrl.indexOf("Editar.html") > 0) {
    RMOPaisService.getListaRMOPaises().then(function(e) {

      $scope.listaRMOPaises = e.data;

    });
  }
}
```

**Así tengo el código de ciudad**

```
/* Carga los paises dependiendo de la ciudad */
$scope.CargarPaisesPorCiudad = function() {
  if ($route.current.loadedTemplateUrl.indexOf("Crear.html") > 0 ||
    $route.current.loadedTemplateUrl.indexOf("Editar.html") > 0) {
    if ($scope.labelSeleccionePais) {
      $scope.disableCiudad = true;
    }

 RMOCiudadService.getListaRMOCiudadesPorPais($scope.solicitud.Ciudad.Pais).then(function(e) {
      $scope.disableCiudad = false;
      $scope.listaRMOCiudades = e.data;
    });
  }
};
```

Así es el objecto cuando está lleno

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Nombre": "Medellin",
  "IdPais": 1,
  "Pais": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Nombre": "Colombia"
  }
}
```